# How run a scrapy spider programmatically like a simple script?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I created a Scrapy spider. But I wanna run it as a script. How I can do this.
Now I am  able to run by this command in terminal:

```
$ scrapy crawl book -o book.json
```

But I want to run it like a simple python script

[image]

Comment: instead  ''scrapy crawl book -o book.json'' i wanna run it as we run simple script

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can run spider directly in python script without using project.

You have to use `scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess` or `scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner`
but I'm not sure if it has all functionality as in project.

See more in documentation: [Common Practices](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html)

Or you can put your command in bash script on Linux or in `.bat` file on Windows.

BTW: on Linux you can add shebang in first line (`#!/bin/bash`) and set attribute "executable" -
ie. `chmod +x your_script` - and it will run as normal program.

---

Working example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    allowed_domains = ['http://quotes.toqoute.com']

    #start_urls = []

    #def start_requests(self):
    #    for tag in self.tags:
    #        for page in range(self.pages):
    #            url = self.url_template.format(tag, page)
    #            yield scrapy.Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

# --- it runs without project and saves in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv',
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Answer (score -1):

The OS module in python provides functions for interacting with the operating system.

It could be of use here:

```
import os
os.system('scrapy crawl book -o book.json')
```

Comment: Bad idea if you're runing crawlers with selenium.

Answer (score -2):

Would a shell script be okay? Such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
scrapy crawl book -o book.json
```