# Running Python Scrapy Spider on a Schedule

Tags: python, cron, scrapy, web-crawler, schedule

I'm new to Python and web scraping. Pls excuse me for my ignorance. In this program I want to run Scrapy Spider on a schedule. I already tried with "schedule" package. But it was not a success since do() method need an method call as an argument. I tried passing class name "MySpider", But it didn't produce the desired output.
I also tried cron jobs. But couldn't figure out how to run Spider as a cron job. Please help me to understand how to run this on a schedule. Any help would be appreciated. I use Python 3.7 on Mac OS

```
import csv
import os
import random
from time import sleep
import scrapy
import schedule
import time

class Myspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider1"

    with open("data.csv", "a") as filee:

        if os.stat("data.csv").st_size != 0:
            filee.truncate(0)
        filee.close()

    def start_requests(self):
        list = ["https://www.example.com/item1",
                "https://www.example.com/item2",
                "https://www.example.com/item3",
                "https://www.example.com/item4",
                "https://www.example.com/item5"
                ]

        for i in list:
            yield scrapy.Request(i, callback=self.parse)
            sleep(random.randint(0, 5))

    def parse(self, response):
        product_name = response.css('#pd-h1-cartridge::text')[0].extract()
        product_price = response.css(
            '.product-price .is-current, .product-price_total .is-current, .product-price_total ins, .product-price ins').css(
            '::text')[3].extract()


        with open('data.csv', 'a+') as file:
            itemwriter = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            itemwriter.writerow([str(product_name).strip(), str(product_price).strip()])
            file.close()

 schedule.every(120).seconds.do(Myspider)

        while 1:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Cron seems like the best thing to try here - what did your cron attempt look like and what was the error?

Comment: @Jay Since this is spider script, I couldn't figure out how to run this as a cron job.

Comment: What cron entry did you use?  E.g., `*/2 * * * * cd project_dir && scrapy crawl spider1`.  You'll likely need to do some extra work in bash to get the python environment to be correct if you're using an environment manager.

Comment: * * * * * python /Users/amal/PycharmProjects/WebScraping/spiders/Myspider.py

Comment: Check out the scrapy tutorial - you can use the scrapy CLI to run your spiders. Simply calling the class doesn't do anything: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#how-to-run-our-spider, also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793131/how-run-a-scrapy-spider-programmatically-like-a-simple-script

Comment: @Jay Thank you for the tips. I will try them out.