# Use scrapy from a py file (not in command line)

Tags: python, scrapy

Trying to launch scrapy from a py file with this command :

```
py myproject.py -f C:\Users\admin\Downloads\test.csv
```

Here my file named "myproject.py"

```
import spiders.ggspider as MySpiders

# Return array
dataFile = args.file
myData = CSVReader.getAnimalList(dataFile)
leSpider = MySpiders.GGCSpider()
leSpider.myList = myData 
leSpider.start_requests()
```

Here my spider file :

```
import scrapy
import urllib

class GGSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spiderman"
    domain = "https://www.google.fr/?q={}"
    myList = []
   
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start_requests(self):
        for leObject in self.myList:
            tmpURL = self.domain.format(urllib.parse.urlencode({'text' : leObject[0]}))
            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.domain+leObject[0],callback = self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print('hello')
        print(response)
```

My problem is : I go into start_requests, because I put a print before the yield and got the print in console
But the callback seems to not append (I don't get the 'Hello' print).

I really don't know why (I'm new to Python, maybe I'm missing something obvious)

Comment: Take a look at [How run a scrapy spider programmatically like a simple script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47794002/7088596)

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't go into self.start_requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's because generator doesn't actually runs before you'll retrieve its values. You could try to consume generator somehow:

```py
import spiders.ggspider as MySpiders

# Return array
dataFile = args.file
myData = CSVReader.getAnimalList(dataFile)
leSpider = MySpiders.GGCSpider()
leSpider.myList = myData 

for request in leSpider.start_requests():
    do_something(request)
```

UPD: Here is a better [example of running Spider from a script](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script):

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "items.json": {"format": "json"},
    },
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I begin to understand. Now with the for loop I can display the request. But the callback is still not triggered and request does not have response

Comment: @Ritooon, I extended the answer with better example from the documentation

Comment: Thanks to you I succeed, I'll update my question to add the solution. Thanks !