# Scheduling a Scrapy spider that has items and pipelines

Tags: python

Does anyone know how to schedule a scrapy spider that has items and pipelines using crontab, I tried but my cron job does not run. I think the issue is the fact that my spider uses scrapy item containers and pipelines. Im using the CrawlerProcess to run my spider as a python file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just simply called the class. if so, nothing happens.

Check out the Scrapy tutorial - you can use the Scrapy CLI to run your spiders: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#how-to-run-our-spider , also: [How run a scrapy spider programmatically like a simple script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793131/how-run-a-scrapy-spider-programmatically-like-a-simple-script)